# Selenium (python) script for a repetitive task lacking efficiency

Tags: python, html, selenium, element, webautomation

I have the script below copy and pasted 51 times creating 2,300 lines of code in order to do the same task, with a single line of code changing for every block, 51 times. **I have two questions moving forward with this project:**

***1. How can I have a prompt in terminal asking for user input for 3 variables that the script re-uses 51 times? The variables are:***

-The '#entries' part in, 
`driver.find_element_by_id("quickpostHashTag").send_keys("**#entries**",(Keys.RETURN))`

-The 'Title' part in,
`driver.find_element_by_id('calendarTitle').send_keys('**Title**')`

-The 'Desc' part in,
`driver.find_element_by_id('calendarMessage').send_keys('**Desc**')`

***And 2. Is it possible to create a list with the 51 element Xpaths and have my script grab the element paths one by one and looping through the actions?*** 
- The line:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('**/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[2]/h3/a[3]**').click()
```

Is a path of an element (1/51) that is the only part changing across those 51 copy/pasted scripts mentioned before and the only part of this path changing is the .../li[2]/... as it goes 1,2,3...49,50,51.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("website")
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email@email.com")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("pass123")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit").click()
driver.get("website2")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_id("ui-id-6").click()
day = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(day).click().perform()
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[2]/h3/a[3]")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)","")


driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[2]/h3/a[3]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[3]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[2]/i').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[3]/ul[1]/li[1]/i').click()

driver.find_element_by_id('scheduleDate').click()
day = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/a')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(day).click().perform()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/button[2]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(img).click().perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li/div[1]/img').click()
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, 500)')
driver.find_element_by_id("quickpostHashTag").send_keys("#entries",(Keys.RETURN))
driver.find_element_by_id("calendarTitle").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('calendarTitle').send_keys('Title')
driver.find_element_by_id('calendarMessage').clear()
driver.find_element_by_id('calendarMessage').send_keys('Desc')
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/form/div[4]/a').click()
driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/button[1]").click()
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use input() 
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

```
>>> entries, title, desc = input().split()
input1 input2 input3
>>> entries
'input1' (output)
```

2. use string.split('/')
   https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
>> s = 'html/body/main/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/ul/li[2]/h3/a[3]'
>> li = s.split('/')
>> li
['html', 'body', 'main', 'div[2]', 'div[6]', 'div[3]', 'div[4]', 'div', 'div[2]', 'table', 'tbody', 'tr', 'td', 'ul', 'li[2]', 'h3', 'a[3]']
>> for i in li:
    #do_something
```

Comment: I don't think I was clear, sorry! So the long code example I provided is run 51 times to do the same task with small tweaks. Once the script is done with the 51 different tasks I need to make appropriate edits for a total of 4 lines to run it again - which is very tedious to do... So let me rephrase: Can I 'wrap' everything to one var/dic (whatever is appripriate) EXCEPT for those 4 lines that I can easily edit once the first batch of tasks (51) is done?